# Need help with ATtiny85 code

Tags: attiny85

I am looking for help with ATtiny85 coding. The project I am working on is using an Arduino Nano and I want to switch to an ATtiny85.

The code below works with the Nano but not with the ATtiny85. I am relatively new to Arduinos and have done a few projects with success but this is my first time using an ATtiny.

I will try to explain. When the code is running on a Nano

- It is checking for a number between 1 and 32 in the EEPROM at address 0.
- If the number is outside either value it will generate a random number between 18 and 32.
- I then check to see if the value at address 0 in the EEPROM is less than or equal to 0, if not it will decrement that value and store the new value in address 0.
- Once the value is at 0 or less a separate value is generated for a time delay.
- Once that time delay has occurred pin 7 outputs power for 1 second and stops.
- Once that has occurred a new random number is generated and stored in address 0.
- To decrement the value the Nano is powered off and on again and the check is made.

I have tested this code with a Nano multiple times and with pin 7 connected to an led it turns on and off, resets and begins again. When I load this code onto an ATtiny85 and run the same test the led will not turn on, also I get an error with the `Serial.begin(9600)` and anything else starting with Serial, so I comment them out and it compiles and uploads just fine. I have the Spark Fun AVR programmer and was able to get the ATtiny to blink an led using a simple led blink sketch but that's as far as I got. I need some help.

```cpp
    #include <EEPROM.h>  // Include the EEPROM library
    
    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);          // Initialize the serial communication
      pinMode(7, OUTPUT);          // Use digital pin 7 as output
      randomSeed(analogRead(0));   // Seed the random number generator with a random value
      int value = EEPROM.read(0);  // Read the value stored in EEPROM address 0
    
      if (value <= -1 || value > 32) {  // If the value is not between 1 and 32
        int new_Value = random(18, 32);  // Generate a new random number between 18 and 32
        EEPROM.write(0, new_Value);    // Store the new value in EEPROM address 0
        Serial.println("Generated a new random number: " + String(new_Value));
      }
    
      else if (value <= 0) {     // Check if the random value is less than or equal to 0
        value--;                 // If no then decrement the value
        EEPROM.write(0, value);  // Write the new value to EEPROM address 0
        Serial.println("Random number from EEPROM: " + String(value));
      }
    
      else {
        int time_delay = random(1, 25);  // Generate random number for time delay
        Serial.println("Generated Time Delay: " + String(time_delay));
       
        delay(1000 * time_delay);
    
        digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
        delay(1000);
        digitalWrite(7, LOW);
    
        int new_Value = random(18, 32);  // Generate new random day value
        EEPROM.write(0, new_Value);    // Write new value to EEPROM address 0
        Serial.println("Generated a new random number: " + String(new_Value));
      }
    }
    void loop() {
    }
```

Sketch used for LED blink

```cpp
    void setup() {    
      pinMode(0, OUTPUT);
    }
    
    void loop() {
      digitalWrite(0, HIGH);   
      delay(5000);                      
      digitalWrite(0, LOW);  
      delay(5000);
```

Comment: `does not work` is not a useful description of a program behavior ... what exactly happens when you run the program?

Comment: `was able to get the ATtiny to blink an led` ...look at your blink LED code and compare to this code

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/47616/37523

Comment: @VE7JRO, I will give that a try, thank you.

Comment: if the blink program works, then why did you not use the same pin for your program?

Comment: When you put this code on the nano you use pin 7.  When you put it on the ATtiny85 what pin number do you use?

Comment: `if (value <= -1 || value > 32)` - I don't see how a single byte, which will range between 0 and 255 could ever be less than 0.

Comment: @NickGammon value is of type (signed) int so it can be less than 0

Comment: @SBF `EEPROM.read()` returns uint8_t which is unsigned. I realise `value` can hold negative numbers, but since its value is put there by `EEPROM.read()` it won't, in this particular case, ever be negative.